# php- how to randomize first and last two digits?

Tags: php, random

I want to know how I can randomize **first** and **last two** digits in php? Suppose the current code is:

```
FJA793HIYX
```

then after randomizing it should be:

```
HJA793HIGD
```

How can I do that?

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: just create the random strings on both trailing and leading. then concatenate the middle

Comment: The first and last two *characters* of your string are not digits; did you mean alphanumeric characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$str = 'HJA793HIGD';
$filter = substr($str,1,7);
echo $newstr= randLetter().$filter.randLetter().randLetter();
function randLetter() {
  $int = rand(0,26);
  $alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  $rand_letter = $alpha[$int];
  return $rand_letter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
$randomDigit = substr( "123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" ,mt_rand( 0 ,34 ) ,1 ) .substr( md5( time() ), 1)
```

Comment: Will that work? I want to randomize a specific string. I dont want to generate a random string and change its first &last two digits. I'm unsure what "abcdef.....ABCDEF ...." mean there and also why you used time()